# How do I copy an ordered list in the same order as is

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-explorer

I have an AVS machine (a psychowalkman)  and a micro SD card 8GB in it.
There is a sorted list of files with appendices .lax and .mp3.
Now I need to copy the **sorted** list into another micro SD card 8GB (under Win 8.1)
i.e. with the order preserved. How do I do that ?? Many files have the same minute
of creation and **then** they are sorted by first letter in the file name.
But I do need to be the list copied in the same order as in the first micro SD card 8GB.

Comment: Just use xcopy to preserve the current date-time: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb491035(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN . BTW, to be clear, you're not copying a *list*, i.e. a master file naming each item; you're copying the actual files... unless there is a distinct *list* you've not mentioned.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik First, my English is quite poor so we may misunderstand each other. Second, there is some deeper problem with those files: they appear in different order already in the AVS machine than they appear in Win 8 explorer. I.e. the order I wish to preserve is different in the display of the AVS machine than when I insert SD card into the USB in my PC. I do not know how the AVS machine determines the right (for me) order I wish to preserve.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Also, I have asked a new similar question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1565897/reordering-files-in-windows-8-explorer). Can you please have a look at it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try one double `for` loop:

**`for ('(for)do|sort')do copy...`**

- In command-line:

```batch-file
cd /d E: && for /f tokens^=* %I in ('^(for %i in ^(*.mp3^,.lax^)do @echo\%i^)^|sort')do copy "%~fI"+,, "F:\%~nxI"
```

- In bat/cmd file:

```batch-file
@echo off 

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion && cd /d E:
for /f tokens^=* %%I in ('^(for %%i in ^(*.mp3^,.lax^)do echo\%%i^)^|sort
')do copy "%%~fI"+,, "F:\%%~nxI"

endlocal && goto=:EOF
```

---

---

- Inspired in this **[answer](https://superuser.com/a/1366618/969781)** from **[@Michael Harvey](https://superuser.com/users/78120/michael-harvey)**: