# Reordering files in Windows 8 Explorer

Tags: windows-explorer, file-management

I have asked a similar question [elsewhere](https://superuser.com/questions/1565858/how-do-i-copy-an-ordered-list-in-the-same-order-as-is) but this is a bit different. How do I create my **own order** of files in Windows 8 Explorer ? Not by creation date or alphabet, just 1 (or several) new personalized orders.

Comment: Right click on the 'Name' column and choose 'More' at the bottom.  If what you want to sort by isn't on that list, or if even after selecting something new.. it doesn't work.. then you need to be programmer.  Yes, it can be done, but the Win32 shell API is not simple and this will need to be done in a real language by extending the windows shell.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas And this hasn't been done yet by anyone or even modification of an existing program is difficult ?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying sort by so I can't answer this.  If it is NEW, then this can't be done without programmatically extending the [Windows Property System](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/windows-properties-system) within the shell.  It has nothing to do with a program.  It has to do with creating a new COM library.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMasm I just wanted to reorder the list of file names with my mouse so that this order can be saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While an arbitrary item order was possible in XP, the code that enabled this has been removed. You have to sort on a property of the file.

Answer (score 0):

There are *many* additional fields, or tags, Windows stores, such as *Title*, *Length* and *Composers*. These fields can be used to determine the sort order. For example, in the image below, I've sorted on title, descending.

[image: Some additional fields in Windows Explorer]

To display the fields,

- Open Windows Explorer.
- Select *Details* view.
- Right-click the column header.
- Select an additional field to display, or
- Click *More...* to select from a far larger list, including items for document, video files and images.
- If you know the field name, type the first few letters to quickly scroll to it.

Once the field is displayed, click on it to sort in that order, and click again to reverse the sort order.

**But, what if the field is blank?** Notice in the screen-shot that not all *Composers* are defined. In that case, you can edit these fields, or tags, using Windows tools such as the [Media Player](https://www.dummies.com/computers/operating-systems/windows-7/how-to-update-and-correct-song-tags-in-windows-media-player-12/), or with third-party tools, such as [the free MP3Tag](https://www.mp3tag.de/en/), shown below.

[image: MP3Tag]

Comment: Things that come from the file properties don't come from *NTFS System Volume Information*.  They come from a simple COM dll that queries the file when called through the shell API.. for MP3s, it reads the tag information.. plain and simple.  Otherwise, how would this work with other file systems?  The system indexer stores this information in an internal database to speed subsequent queries.